# Dual boot with SSD and hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, desktop

I have a PC with an SSD drive containing Windows 7 and a hard drive for files.  The harddrive has about 500GB of free space.

I want to install Windows 8 on a new partition.  Can I setup the partition using space from the hard drive or must I use the SSD drive?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can only have 0 or 1 master boot record.  This means if you want to boot from multiple HDs you'll need to tap your 'Boot from' button at startup and select your HD that way.  Otherwise partition the SSD and get your nice 'Select your OS' menu.

Comment: Yep, you should be able to provision out some space on a new partition and just make that bootable and modify your bootloader to pickup the changes.